# Adding Javascript Text Watermark doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a textbox watermark using javascript but with the current code I get a error

Webpage error details
Message: 'searchInput' is undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function watermark(inputId,text){ 

  var inputBox = document.getElementById(searchInput); 

      if (inputBox.value.length > 0){  

           if (inputBox.value == text)  

                  inputBox.value = '';
  }   
    else   
       inputBox.value = text;
 }
</script>

<input name="keyword2" id="searchInput" type="text" class="searchbox2"
       value="Enter a State, County, City or Zip" size="77" maxlength="30"
       onfocus="watermark('searchInput','Enter a State, County, City or Zip');"
       onblur="watermark('searchInput','Enter a State, County, City or Zip');"/>
```

Comment: Would be so nice if all browsers supported the html5 placeholder attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes around searchInput.

getElementById accepts a string, you are referencing an undeclared variable.

```
document.getElementById('searchInput');
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot that! DO you happe to know how to style text in the input to gray?

Comment: sure, just add this in your css `#searchInput { color: #666 }`

Answer (score 1):

The variable your function expects is named `inputId` not `searchInput`..

So change this line

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById(searchInput);
```

to

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById(inputId);
```

---

**An alternative**

And to avoid naming the element completely, just pass `this` as the first argument as it will reference the element

```
function watermark(element, text) {
    if (element.value.length > 0) {
        if (element.value == text) {
            element.value = '';
        }
    }
    else element.value = text;
}
```

and

```
<input name="keyword2" id="searchInput" type="text" class="searchbox2"
       value="Enter a State, County, City or Zip" size="77" maxlength="30"
       onfocus="watermark(this,'Enter a State, County, City or Zip');"
       onblur="watermark(this,'Enter a State, County, City or Zip');"/>
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ZtutT/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around your search input getElementById Declaration, like so:

`document.getElementById('searchInput');`

Also, a more direct and simple way of doing this is by putting this in your input:

`onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"`

Hope this helps :)